# 2 different certificates seen from 2 different VMs

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, infrastructure

I am having trouble understanding a problem that I have. I am seeking help to understand what is happening. Hopefully someone can help me.

First let me give you some context:
One of our providers at work gave us 2 urls in order to access his service. These 2 urls are URLs for their primary and secondary site. In our system, we are always sending requests to the primary site. If the primary site is not available, we try to use the secondary site.

A few weeks ago, the certificate of our provider changed. We proceeded to the change. The certificate is a wild card certificate (it applies for both urls). Everything seemed to work perfectly on our qualification environnement. But we noticed a strange behavior on production.

We performed on our machines the following openssl request:

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect <PROVIDER_URL_1:443> 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates
```

For the primary URL, everything is working fine, openssl request shows the certificate is valid:

```
notBefore=Jun 20 00:00:00 2016 GMT
notAfter=Aug 19 23:59:59 2018 GMT
```

But when I perform the exact same openssl request with the secondary URL, I find the previous certificated
    echo | openssl s_client -connect  2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates

```
notBefore=May 15 00:00:00 2014 GMT
notAfter=Jul 13 23:59:59 2016 GMT
```

I don't understand why our production environnement sees 2 different certificates for PROVIDER_URL_1 and PROVIDER_URL_2 when on our qualification environnement both URLs provide the same wildcard certificate.

Do you guys have any idea what seems to be the problem here ?

Comment: One of two things come to mind... (1) Your are not using TLS or SNI, so you are getting the "default" server with the `s_client` command. In this case, you need to add both `-tls1` and `-servername` options. (2) The services are probably behind a load balancer. The servers participating in the backend group are not configured the same. You should contact your service provider if its a problem. I'm guessing its a problem because it breaks Public Key Pinning (real pinning, not the IETF/Browser rendition).

Comment: Thank you for your answer jww, the problem came from our provider. They found they found a network mis configuration and now everything is ok!